# Screen goes black then program crashes

Tags: android, debugging

I have a problem i have been hunting down for the last day and i cant seem to find what is wrong.  I have been working on this app for about a month without too many problems.  I started working on the main interface page and one button into it this problem rears its ugly head.  The problem is the screen shows up and then disappears about 30 seconds later.  After watching the error it has a particular method of things happening.  First my bitmaps go, then the texts after about a second, then the screen is black for about 5 seconds, then i get my phone background then about 10 seconds later the my apps show up.  I never get a force close message.  Id rather understand what is causing the problem then having someone tell me to change something so i can prevent it from happening again. So i don't want to post my code just yet.

other tidbits:

all my graphics are using the canvas method

since i got a 30 second window i continued working on the framework of my project the problem still has the same timing after finishing a good portion of it

the graphics i used from the working portion of my code are the same in my nonworking

the screen has no functionality to it right now its just graphics

I get the feeling i cant avoid posting my code but please try to answer it without asking for it.

Comment: can you at least post a stack trace?

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Accept answers that work. Post error messages/stack traces, if any.

Comment: what device are you running on?

Comment: My first guess would be that you're doing too much work on the UI thread since the crash has regular timing. Android kicks you off after about 5 seconds without returning, but usually that results in an ANR. Could you give us the logcat output?

Comment: well i guess my newbie thumb sticks out today its a memory leak.  Thanks stevehb i didn't even know the logcat existed any suggestions on filtering so i can get you the logcat without the useless info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Steve for letting me know about the logcat.  After updating Eclipse it became much easier to read.  The problem was, not enough garbage collecting.  Ironically the code that seem to be giving me problems was not the problem it was just the straw that broke the camels hump.

I have chopped up my code enough to where it is workable but i still have a lot ahead of me to fix the issue 100%.